# Apartment buildings higher than the shul

Tags: synagogue, maseches-shabbos, architecture-design, home-house, size

[Shabbat 11a](http://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.11a.3-6?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all) states that a city in which houses (but not towers or castles/fortresses [unsure about the translation]) are built higher than the synagogue will eventually be destroyed.

> ואמר רבא בר מחסיא אמר רב חמא בר גוריא אמר רב כל עיר שגגותיה גבוהין מבית הכנסת לסוף חרבה שנאמר (עזרא ט, ט) לרומם את בית אלהינו ולהעמיד את חרבותיו וה"מ בבתים אבל בקשקושי ואברורי [רש"י -- בירניות ומגדלים] לית לן בה

**How does this apply to apartment buildings?** We might say that they are like houses -- after all, people live in them, and that would be a problem. On the other hand, perhaps they are like a castle, which is normally built large, which sounds to be permissible.

Comment: Not really related to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62579/what-is-the-ideal-design-of-a-synagogue which uses the same source. I've been wondering for a while, and finally posted now because i saw the other question and so i didn't have to go look for the source. :P